# Need help finding a file that is corrupting my NN

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, tf.keras

I have created a Neural Network to help identify children's images and give them grades based on a pre-trained criteria. The problem is the web **scraper** I used must've downloaded either an unknown file or a file not supported by tensorflow for use with the NN. I have the two training and validation directory split into 5 separate categories that allows each image to be given a label based on the categories. I have tried running a basic loop to print the damaged or missing file but it will not display the correct file. My model throws an error when compiling the fit statement and gives me an
`"PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x0000022B6AC4E900>"` error. This is the code I'm using to quickly run through the directories to search for the errored file as it seems to be a webp problem.

```
filepaths = [V, T]
bad_file = []
for fp in filepaths:
    # Split the extension from the path 
    ext = os.path.splitext(fp)[-1].lower()

    if ext == ".jpg":
        print (fp, "is an jpg!")
    elif ext == ".jpeg":
        print (fp, "is a jpeg file!")
    #elif ext == ".webp":
     #   print (fp, "is a flac file!")
    elif ext == ".png":
        print (fp, "is a png file!")    
    else:
        bad_file.append(fp)
        #os.remove(fp)
        print (fp, "is an unknown file format.")
        print(bad_file)
```

Any help on
A) Trying to decode the io_bytes image as I cannot find a reliable and clean-cut source
b) Helping write a function to search the directory for error files

Any and all help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

checking the extension is probably not sufficient. I think you should read in the images and test the shape  as in

```
import cv2
# put the code below inside the loop
bad_listt=[]
try:
    img=cv2.imread(fp)
    shape=img.shape
except:
    print ('file ', fp, '  is not a proper image file')
    bad_list.append (fp)
```